# Mobile Safari iOS 8 - no more poster frame for HTML5 video

Tags: ios, html5-video

Simple web pages using HTML5 video no longer work in iOS 8.0.2 as they did in iOS 7 -- or at least that's what I'm seeing on my iPad.

Specifically, a web page viewed in mobile Safari in iOS 8 (or the iOS version of Chrome) no longer displays the auto-generated poster frame for an HTML5 video. Instead, there's just a grey triangle in a light grey circle. See http://web.wellesley.edu/video/html5/b.html on your iOS 8 device for an example. The auto-generated poster frame displays fine in desktop Safari and Chrome.

If one creates a specific poster image and adds the poster attribute (e.g., poster="poster.jpg"), iOS 8 will show the poster -- but that shouldn't be necessary. In iOS 7, the first frame of the video was automatically displayed to the user.

Are others seeing this? Any idea what broke, or how to fix it (besides adding the poster attribute?)

Thanks...k

Comment: I have the same issue - did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Unfortunately, I've heard nothing back from anyone. Either nobody else is seeing this problem, or nobody else cares. It's unsolved as of now.